# Getting only data for specified HTTP method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, crud

I'm just playing around with Laravel at the moment, trying to work out if it is a good choice of framework to use for a project.

I've downloaded the generator bundle from [here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) and created a resource, following the documentation.

This gives me a form with author and body.

The store method that gets generated looks like this:

```
/**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();
        $validation = Validator::make($input, Tweet::$rules);

    if ($validation->passes())
    {
        $this->tweet->create($input);

        return Redirect::route('tweets.index');
    }

    return Redirect::route('tweets.create')
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
}
```

It seems to work OK, except that the $input array contains $_GET variables as well as $_POST.  It validates OK but causes an exception when it tries to save the model as it contains unexpected fields (anything from the $_GET superglobal gets added to the query).

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tweets' in
>   'field list' (SQL: insert into `tweets` (`author`, `body`, `tweets`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) (Bindings: array (
>   0 => 'zzz', 1 => 'zzzzz', 2 => '', 3 => '2013-07-02 10:23:16', 4 =>
>   '2013-07-02 10:23:16', ))

Is there a way to only pass the relevant values or do I have to manually remove anything that I don't want to use?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can pass selective input variables to the withInput() method.

This is how your code would look like:

return Redirect::route('tweets.create')
        ->withInput(Input::except('tweets'))
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');


also you can use to pass "selective inputs" or remove "selective inputs from all input vars". Here is the code you can use:-


$input = Input::only('username', 'password');  // selective inputs

$input = Input::except('tweets'); // remove selective inputs
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there is currently no way in Laravel 4 to only retrieve either $_GET or $_POST input using the `Input::all();` method, but there are the `Input::only()` and the `Input::except()` methods which if you're not aware of, do exactly what they say on the tin...

Simply pass them an array of the keys you want to include in your string

```
$input = Input::only('author', 'body','tweets');
```

OR an array of keys you want to exclude

```
$input = Input::except('updated_at');
```

And it will only retrieve the values you specified (Or the values you didn't exclude). I know it's not as easy as some sort of `Input::all('post');` function, but it's the only way without changing Laravel around yourself. I think this could be a good addition to the framework personally

Answer (score 0):

Simplest possible way to get POST (PUT, etc) variables in  Laravel 4 is the following:

`$post = Input::duplicate(array())->all();`

which means: take the current request, clone it, and replace $_GET parameters with an empty array.

You may have to further investigate `duplicate()` to learn how to avoid further collissions with cookies etc.